# Isn’t “Eye-glazing” a popular word? Why isn’t it included in major English dictionaries?

Tags: vocabulary, is-it-a-word

I came across the word *eye-glazing* in the article of today’s Time magazine (Sept 9) titled ‘Slow Down! Why Some Languages Sound So Fast?’, which I'm sure will interest 'language buffs'.

It begins with (Sorry for a bit lengthy):

> “Here's one of the least-interesting paragraphs you've ever read:
>
> 'Last night I opened the front door to let the cat out. It was such a beautiful night that I wandered down to the garden to get a breath of fresh air. Then I heard a click as the door closed behind me.’
>
> OK, it becomes a little less *eye-glazing* after that, with the speaker getting arrested while trying to force the door back open. Still, we ain't talking Noel Coward here.”

I checked online dictionaries to find the exact meaning of *eye-glazing*. I was able to find many examples of usages of this word, e.g.,

> - But the rest of my audience was growing restive, with here and there an *eye glazing* over. —The Burglar on the Prowl
> - I mean, thousands of pages, stuff that's almost *eye glazing* to read. —CNN Transcript Dec 4, 2002
> - The statute has become such an *eye glazing* mess that it’s easy to forget that in 1965 it was beautifully designed and absolutely essential. —The Volokh Conspiracy

From the above examples I guessed the word means ‘making eyes unfocused, blurred’ (Correct me if I'm wrong), but I couldn’t find its definition in any dictionaries including Cambridge, Merriam-Webster Online, nor Urban Dictionary.

I wonder why *eye-glazing* which looks as if very colloquial is not registered in any dictionaries, while they accommodate eye-related compounds such as 'eye opening,' 'eye-catching,' and 'eye popping'. Isn’t *eye-glazing* a popular word?

Comment: As for dictionaries: "1977   N.Y. Times 14 Sept. c21/1   The proceedings..ran on for an eye-glazing three-and-a-half hours."; 
"2012   Atlantic Oct. 68/1   Campaign finance is a deeply boring subject, so eye-glazing that one might almost suspect a conspiracy to make it that way." (OED) http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/67296

Comment: First, it not a word. And no, it's not all that popular. It's just a phrase, not much of a set phrase, certainly not an idiom. So it doesn't figure as a main entry in dictionaries or words, phrases or idioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Eye-glazing" isn't that common at all. "Eye glazing over" is certainly used, as in "his eyes glazed over". In your main example, the person is commenting on "one of the least-interesting paragraphs" you have ever read, and he is saying, "ok, after these very boring paragraphs, it gets less boring(eye-glazing)".
The term "eye glazing" is usually used in the sense that the person is so [bored](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glaze_over) that his eye glazes over. Also, the "The Burglar on the Prowl" example has the same meaning of boredom.

But is this common? Is "eye glazing" common usage? Taking  a look at an Ngram:

[image]

By far, "glaze over" is used the most, whereas "eye glazing" although it is used, is not that common. 
Perhaps that's why it isn't included in most dictionaries.

Comment: I don't know where you get that *"...person enjoys this so much that his eye [glazes over]"* meaning from. So far as I'm concerned, "eye-glazing" stuff is *always* "mind-numbingly boring". Certainly that's the case in all OP's examples. But I agree with @Cerberus - I'd either say "mind-numbing" or "eyes glazed over".

Comment: I heard people say, "When she eats that fruit cake, her eyes glazes over." It's used for pleasure as well

Comment: @Thursagen Not much any longer. (Where I live.)

Answer (score 12):

I usually hear this as **his eyes glazed over** or **glazed-over eyes**; the phrase *glaze over* seems well documented: [*glaze over* on Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/%20glaze%20over). Your derived adjective *eye-glazing* sounds less common to my canine ears, though still perfectly clear.

Comment: It took me far too long to realise why you'd have canine ears. (facepalm!)

Comment: @JamesWebster How could you? He has 6 of them!

Comment: That's not the question, though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think ‘eye glazing’ is as common a term as eye-opening, which has almost become a single word.

There is a journalistic term *mego* (from - My Eyes Glaze Over) used to describe a passage of long winded poetic description dropped into a scene.

Answer (score 3):

"Eye-glazing" means "so boring/tiresome that it makes you sleepy". Remember that Tom & Jerry episode where Tom has to tape his eyelids to pretend he is standing guard? He was dead tired but wanted/had to stay awake (like you do, too, in order to finish the article) so he tried to force his eyes open. What happened then? His eyes glazed!

Comment: Weird, I've usually understood the word to mean something a bit more general like "not comprehending", often for reasons like not having the technical background to understand a speaker, or having been overloaded with details - but not necessarily bored per se.

Comment: As opposed to "eye glazing" (un-hyphenated), i.e. ***spectacles***.